# Disable Template(Mustache) Caching in Spring Boot 1.5.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, templates, spring-boot

I am using Mustache template engine with Spring Boot. 
Mustache compiler is https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java

Now, while development I don't want Spring Boot to cache the templates. The templates reside in **main > resources > templates**

I have tried the adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

This restarts the server whenever I make any change in the Java files but not in case of template files. (Although I don't want it to restart the server when the templates are changed)

Again I have added one **application.properties** file in same directory where the Main Application exists, which look like this.

```
spring.template.cache: false
spring.cache.type : false
```

This also doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Instead of wildly trying to add properties you might want to read [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). Hint check the `spring.mustache` properties.